# Rails: Struggling with Associations (nested comments)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, comments, associations

First off, I apologize for the amount of code and for what I'm asking. But I need help desperately. I can't wrap my head around this concept whatsoever.

I have a basic CRUD (projects) and I'm trying to nest another CRUD (discussions) to projects so that there can be a discussion for each project. Now, I have been trying to do this for five days straight. I can't figure it out for the life of me. I've read and researched everything there is to be read and researched. I can't figure it out on my own.

So, I've started fresh. I've set up a new project and got the basics, but I have no clue where to go from here. I would be so incredibly appreciative if someone could take the time to write me step by step instructions. Or, if you're able to do it quick, perhaps even finish my code for me? Because I'm going to have to do about 5 more of these, so if I were to have 1 fully completed one I could reference that would be so amazing.

projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  def show


  end

  def new
    @projects = Project.new

  end

  def create #no view
    @projects = Project.new(project_params)
    if @projects.save
      redirect_to projects_path, :notice => "Your project was sent!"
    else 
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @projects = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update #no view
    @projects = Project.find(params[:id])

    if @projects.update_attributes(project_params)
      redirect_to projects_path, :notice => "Your project has been updated."
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy #no view
    @projects = Project.find(params[:id])
    @projects.destroy
    redirect_to projects_path, :notice => "Your project has been deleted."
  end

  private
  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description)
  end


end
```

discussions_controller.rb

```
class DiscussionsController < ApplicationController


  def index
    @discussion = Discussion.all
  end

  def show
    @discussions = Discussion.find(params[:id])
    @projects = @discussions.Project.all
  end

  def new
    @discussions = Discussion.new

  end

  def create #no view
    @discussions = Discussion.new(discussion_params)
    if @discussions.save
      redirect_to discussions_path, :notice => "Your discussion was submitted."
    else 
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @discussions = Discussion.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update #no view
    @discussions = Discussion.find(params[:id])

    if @discussions.update_attributes(discussion_params)
      redirect_to discussions_path, :notice => "Your discussion has been updated."
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy #no view
    @discussions = Discussion.find(params[:id])
    @discussions.destroy
    redirect_to discussions_path, :notice => "Your discussions has been deleted."
  end

  private
  def discussion_params
    params.require(:discussion).permit(:title, :description)
  end

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :homes
  resources :projects
  resources :discussions

  root "homes#index"
```

Models:

discussion.rb

```
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :discussions
end
```

Migrates:

_create_projects.rb

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.date :due_date

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

_create_discussions.rb

```
class CreateDiscussions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :discussions do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

_create_nested_discussions

```
class NestedDiscussion < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :discussions, :project_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: There isn't a problem with this code itself as I restarted the project. This is about my third or fourth attempt at restarting, so I was showing what I have in hopes someone could guide me through it. I already read all of the documentation but I'm still not getting it. Maybe I just suck at googling but I'm not able to find many useful tutorials on this.

Comment: You are off to a good start with your code, but telling us you are "not getting it" does not tell us what your problem is. Not getting what? Is there an error code you are getting? Be specific.

Comment: @ThomasO I guess I mean I don't really understand anything after this point. I'm not sure what comes next. There's no specific error or anything, I'm just not entirely sure what to do. Now I've read the documentation and whatnot, but what I've read just kind of tells syntax but not when/where to use it. I've been looking around for associations tutorials but can't really find anything that isn't outdated or to complex.

Comment: Well I mean... if you try to use your application, does it work? If it works, it is done. If it doesn't work, you often get some sort of error. We can use that error to help you fix your application.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that you don't permit project_id attribute in your strong parameters. So add `:project_id` in your params in discussions_controller.rb:

```
private
def discussion_params
  params.require(:discussion).permit(:title, :description, :project_id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want your routes to be as such:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :discussions
end
```